# Blur page background through div?

Tags: javascript, css

I've seen the other post with pretty much this same question, but I don't understand how to implement it. I've got a .css file that is linked to my html file. How would I use "blurfast.js" to get a blurred div background? Can I just do something like this?

`mydiv {background:blurfast;}`

in my .css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Pixastic.process(domeDiv, "blurfast", {amount:1});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is made to work only on images so will not work for your requirements as far as  I know!
for an image the javascript below should work!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = document.getElement("myImage");
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", {amount:1});
</script>
```